# How to create WAR for Spark 1.1.1 application?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, war, spark-java

I've created nice application using [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/). Now I want to deploy it to Apache Tomcat 7. I've tried to build WAR using Apache Ant:

```
<target name="war">
  <war destfile="ROOT.war"
       webxml="web.xml">
     <classes dir="classes"/>
  </war>
</target>
```

I've placed compiled code into classes folder. In web.xml I've placed [officially recommended code](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#other-webserver):

```
<web-app>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
            <param-value>com.MyApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then I've placed ROOT.war into webapps folder, restarted Tomcat and my application isn't deployed.

I've checked catalina.out

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Looks not very informative. Then I've checked localhost logs.

```
Feb 28, 2016 4:02:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter SparkFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: spark.servlet.SparkFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Hm, looks like there is no some Spark JAR in classpath. I've added 
`/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/spark-core-1.1.1.jar`

It looks like there is no `spark.servlet.SparkFilter` there. Do you have any ideas where I can find this jar?
Or if anyone has WAR file ready to deploy, could you share it with me?

I have checked that jar files from `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/` are used by other servlets.

Comment: Have you tried adding the JAR file directly into the WAR task? For example, if the JAR file is in /lib directory, then add <lib dir="libs" /> into the task

Comment: spark-core-1.1.1.jar? Looks like you are using a really old version of Spark. Is this because you can't use Java 8?

Comment: Yes, should I switch to a new one? Is it well known problem with spark-core-1.1.1.jar? I just wonder if I should spend some time on investigation of a new one.

Comment: @vandershraaf yes, that was not helpful.

Comment: v 1.1.1 is realy old. Have a look at the latest version 2.4 which has many bug fixes and improvements. It is possible your issue is related to a bug that has now been fixed.

Comment: @k.liakos thank you, I will. Do you know if there is any Hello World WAR with Spark 2.4? I wish to try to deploy before.

Comment: I am not aware of a ready to use sample war. I could show you an example of how to build one, but I am using maven, and you want ant.

Comment: Maven would be great as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added an example of how you build a war with maven and sparkjava 2.3.

Here is the repository https://github.com/kliakos/sparkjava-war-example with instructions.

The steps are fairly simple. It should work with a fresh Tomcat installation, otherwise it may be some Tomcat related problem you are facing.